# GPS system on the Vehicle

Tags: gps

I am really sorry, if this is the wrong place to post this question. But if it is, I hope it could help someone in the future. If this is a wrong place, where could I post this question? I have looked other stack-exchange sites, but could not decide where to ask it :(

I am developing an application that will use a GPS unit mounted on the car. I am looking for a GPS Dongle provider, and so far I have really seen several of them. They all have shiny websites, and what not. Has anyone ever dealt with this type of technology, and could you recommend a reliable provider.
What I need for my project:

- LAT / LON / Mileage from the Dongle
- Dongle should either allow us to GET the data, or it could POST to our server the data
- Should be using SIM card for internet connection
- LAT / LON should be compatible with Google maps location.

Comment: How many units you need?

Comment: Unknown at this time. Could be hundreds if not more

Comment: Shall the device be hidden, or visible mounted at the screenshield, with some buttons and display?

Comment: Device should be hidden without any UI. It should send data to predefined server/API

Comment: Sorry, i cannot help for hidden without UI.